# In postgres, is it good to use split_part function instead like statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, sql-like

Could someone explain or suggest that can we use ***split_part*** instead of ***like*** in Postgres.

In my use case the name column will contain some middle string which is common for a particular categroy. Like *Vinod.Game1*, *Vinod.Game2*, *Vinod.Game3* etc.

Now I want to fetch Number of games played by *Vinod* & their details.
I have two options :

```
select * from games where name like 'Vinod.Game%'
```

or

```
select * from games where split_part(name, '.Game', 1) = 'Vinod'
```

When I check with a data of 200 rows, i saw beloe stats

For Like query :

```
Planning time: 120.326 ms
 Execution time: 2.878 ms
```

For split_part query :

```
Planning time: 8.845 ms
 Execution time: 3.681 ms
```

Can you please help me in understanding that the impact of planning time in the query. And which is better to use (***split_part*** vs ***like***), if we have giga database?

```
                                              Table "public.games"
      Column      |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |        Default         | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id               | character varying(32) |           | not null |                        | extended |              |
 access           | character varying(50) |           |          |                        | extended |              |
 deleted          | character varying(1)  |           |          | 'N'::character varying | extended |              |
 timePlayed       | character varying(50) |           |          |                        | extended |              |
 description      | character varying     |           |          |                        | extended |              |
 name             | character varying(64) |           |          |                        | extended |              |
```

Comment: That looks unusual. Is that repeatable? How is the table defined?

Comment: Try an index on `(name)`. `LIKE` can use it if the wildcard is only at the end.

Comment: table schema is updated, what is meant by repeatable?

Comment: @stickybit so, if we have index on name, Like is better?

Comment: @VinodKumarChaganti: Potentially yes. But you have to try it for yourself.

Comment: @VinodKumarChaganti . . . Timings on small tables -- such as 200 rows -- are not generally reproducible or particularly meaningful.  Try on a million rows.

Comment: When I try on db<>fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0eb98462f75e116de1a85a771083ee4c) I find that `like` is usually fast, but not actually by very much.  And sometimes `split_part()` wins.  I think that just means that `split_part()` has an efficient implementation.  I would go for three reasons:  (1) it is standard; (2) it usually performance better; (3) it can use an index under some circumstances.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `timePlayed` sounds as if that should be an integer column, not a varchar. And yes/no flags are better stored as `boolean` rather than `varchar`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I changed the column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to fix your data model.

Don't store delimited values in a single column. This will hurt you again and again in the long run.

---

But as usually the answer to problems like that that is "*I didn't create it and I have to live with it*", you need to test the two approaches.

To get a meaningful test, you will have to create substantially more than just 200 rows.

I created some fake data using this approach:

```
create table games
(
 id               character varying(32)  not null,
 access           character varying(50),
 deleted          character varying(1) default 'N'::character varying ,
 timePlayed       character varying(50),
 description      text ,
 name             character varying(64)                                   
);

insert into games(id, access, timeplayed, description, name)
select g.id::text, 
       'full',
       'all night long',
       'some description',
       case 
          when random() < 0.1 then 'Vinod.'
          when random() < 0.2 then 'Vivos.'
          when random() < 0.3 then 'Doniv.'
          when random() < 0.5 then 'Novid.'
          when random() < 0.6 then 'Somevid.'
          when random() < 0.7 then 'OtherVid.'
          when random() < 0.8 then 'Fonod.'
          else 'Barnod.'
       end || 'Game' || (random() * 999 + 1)::int
from generate_series(1,1e6) as g(id);

create index on games (name varchar_pattern_ops);
create index on games  ( (split_part(name, '.', 1)) );
vacuum analyze games;
```

The above generates 1 million rows, 10 percent of them starting with `Vinod.`

Note that I split only on the `.` not on `.Game` - to me that makes more sense: pick the first element delimited by dots.

When the table is cached, I get execution times around 70ms for the LIKE query and about 25ms for the query with `split_part()` (Windows 10 laptop with Postgres 13.2). So split_part() with an expression based index seems to be the winner.

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
select * 
from games 
where name like 'Vinod.Game%';


QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index Scan using games_name_idx on games  (cost=0.42..12490.69 rows=99080 width=59) (actual time=0.018..67.705 rows=100189 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (((name)::text ~>=~ 'Vinod.Game'::text) AND ((name)::text ~<~ 'Vinod.Gamf'::text))                                   
  Filter: ((name)::text ~~ 'Vinod.Game%'::text)                                                                                    
  Buffers: shared hit=99863                                                                                                        
Planning Time: 0.669 ms                                                                                                            
Execution Time: 70.365 ms
```

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
select * 
from games 
where split_part(name, '.', 1) = 'Vinod'

QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index Scan using games_split_part_idx on games  (cost=0.42..11657.32 rows=99400 width=59) (actual time=0.025..20.793 rows=100189 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (split_part((name)::text, '.'::text, 1) = 'Vinod'::text)                                                                   
  Buffers: shared hit=11450                                                                                                              
Planning Time: 0.098 ms                                                                                                                  
Execution Time: 23.605 ms
```

But again: the correct solution to your problem is to normalize your data model.

Answer (score -1):

The fisrt query with LIKE will do a scan of the table (not and index scan because of the ugly "SELECT *"...).

The second query with split_part will construct an internal dataset (the split_part function), and the do a scan on the resulted dataset to find the qulifieds rows.

In the two cases, there will be no index at all that will speed up your query, bacuse your predicate is not sargable.

In fact the data i your query violate the first normal form (atomci data). When such a mistqke is done, your database is not relational at all and when you d'ont have a relational database, the RDBMS cannot treat it with performances, beacuase a RDBMS is espcailly designed to manipulate relation, not "cobol" type data structures !

Comment: The first query can absolutely be supported by a B-Tree index (when using the `varchar_patter_ops` operator class). And for the second query, an expression based index could be created `create index on games  ( (split_part(name, '.Game', 1)) )`. But I agree that this is a horrible database design.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but only if the % joker char is always at the end of the criterion value. For the second, the cost of a functional index on a split will be a lack of performances...

Comment: An expression based index is no more expensive than a regular one.